# Apply css on enabled buttons JavaScript

Tags: jquery, css, button, apply

I have `HTML` page where div and buttons are generating dynamically from `JavaScript` as below.

```
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
  <button class ="xyz" disabled="disabled">Button1</button>
</div>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
  <button class ="xyz" disabled="disabled">Button2</button>
</div>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
  <button class ="xyz">Button3</button>
</div>
```

My requirement is to change the `css(background color)` of that div only in which Button is not disabled which is last div. I'm using jQuery to do this but it is changing css for all the divs above. Please tell me the solution for this requirement in jQuery or JavaScript.

```
$(".xyz").parent().css({ "background": "rgb(95, 49, 49)" });
```

Comment: any reason why you removed me as answer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appply `last()` method before `parent()`, in your case is enough and it works:

```js
$(".xyz").last().parent().css({ "background": "rgb(95, 49, 49)" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
<button class ="xyz" disabled="disabled">Button1</button>
</div>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
<button class ="xyz" disabled="disabled">Button2</button>
</div>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
<button class ="xyz">Button3</button>
</div>
My requirement is to change the css(background color) of that div only in which Button is not disabled which is last div. I'm using jquery to do this but it is changing css for all the divs above. Please tell me the solution for this requirement in jquery or javascript.
```

Comment: What if he changes the order of the buttons, so the enabled button is in the middle, then your code will not provide the correct answer, it should be more dynamic.

Comment: Thats true your answer is more complete, mine only works in the case his button is only at final

Answer (score 2):

You should use a combination of `:not()` and `:disabled`

`:not(:disabled)`

```js
$(".xyz:not(:disabled)").parent().css({ "background": "rgb(95, 49, 49)" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
  <button class="xyz" disabled="disabled">Button1</button>
</div>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
  <button class="xyz" disabled="disabled">Button2</button>
</div>
<div style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
  <button class="xyz">Button3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. This will apply styles to all div's where the button is enabled.

The selector is `button:enabled`.

```
$(function(){
    $("button:enabled").parent().css({ "background": "rgb(95, 49, 49)" }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the job as you said the html is generated dynamically.
This will apply background color to all the buttons (not the specific element) which are enabled (not disabled)

```
$('button:not(:disabled)').parent().css({ "background": "rgb(95, 49, 49)" });
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/md9pthta/

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hvo5fnt1/

Changed JS:

```
$(".xyz").last().css({ "background": "rgb(95, 49, 49)" });
```

Comment: What if the Enabled button is at the position other then last?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7cUbC/25/) fiddle 
I have added below jquery in your code :

`$(".xyz:not(:disabled)").parent().css({ "background": "rgb(95, 49, 49)" });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery selector to find the required element and then change the respective CSS.

Below is your selector:

```
$( ".xyz[disabled!='disabled']" ).parent()
```

Here is Fiddle

[`Fiddle link`](https://jsfiddle.net/09j1g9yd/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector. `.xyz[disabled]` to style disabled buttons and `.xyz` for not disabled.

More on that here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp